# Android 8.0 Oreo wifi list not getting

Tags: android, wifi, wifimanager

On **Android 8.0**, not getting wifi list using wifiManager, below API level 26 I am getting the list.

**This function returns the `WifiManager` Object**

```
public static WifiManager getWifiManager(Context context) {
        WifiManager wifiManager = null;
        try {

            wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return wifiManager;
    }
```

**This function returns the wifi list**

```
public static List<ScanResult> getWifiScanResults(Boolean sorted, Context context) {
    WifiManager wifiManager = NetworkUtil.getWifiManager(context);
    List<ScanResult> wifiList = wifiManager.getScanResults();

    //Remove results with empty ssid
    List<ScanResult> wifiListNew = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ScanResult scanResult : wifiList) {
        if (!scanResult.SSID.equals(""))
            wifiListNew.add(scanResult);
    }
    wifiList.clear();
    wifiList.addAll(wifiListNew);

         return wifiList;
}
```

I had registered the `BroadcastReceiver`

```
WiFiMainActivity.this.registerReceiver(receiverWifi, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
```

**and here is the startScan() Method**

```
   public static void startScan(Context context) {
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiManager.startScan();
    }
```

**User having following permission**

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Not able to track the bug on android 8.0 Oreo, is there any other permission that I am missing.

Comment: I have the same problem. I'm working on an app which uses WiFi scan results to work. Since today I was using a targetSdkVersion 25 and all was working perfectly on Android 8. Today I've just updated the targetSdkVersion to 26 and just noticed that on devices running Android 8 the scan results (via BroadcastReceiver declared in the Manifest) are no longer received.

Only downgrading the targetSdkVersion to 25 works great, but I need a targetSdkVersion 26 or higher, so I'm frustrated right now. There is no info about this problem on the web.

Comment: Could you test your code with a targetSdkVersion 25 instead of 26 and tell me if you receive the wifi list now?

Comment: @MarcEstrada Were you able to fix this? Thank you

Answer (score 7):

Since in `Android 8` was introduced the [background execution limitation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#broadcasts) most of `BroadcastReceiver` actions registered in `Manifest` will be no longer sent nor received except [these ones](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions).

Yes, you are registering it through your `Context` but maybe your code is wrong.

You should register it through your `Application Context` instead of your `Activity Context` to avoid memory leaks. Also, try creating a void `IntentFilter` and adding your action afterwards. This code is working fine in my application with `targetSdkVersion` 26+ in `Android 8 Oreo` (Nexus 5X).

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction("android.net.wifi.SCAN_RESULTS");
context.registerReceiver(new YourBroadcastReceiver(), intentFilter);
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 3):

Your 8.0 android device has to have Location enabled in order for wifimanager to work.

Comment: Yes, I am trying... using location-enabled steel wifimanager not working.

Comment: Even with location enabled, targeting to 26+ Wifi ScanResults stops working

Answer (score 2):

You must ask for the ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission at runtime

```
 @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 0);
            }
        }
    }
```